# Difference between if and if not python

Tags: python

Can anybody please tell me here what is the exact difference between **if and if not** here in the code.

```
def postordertraversse(self,top):

       m=[]
       if(top):            
        if not self.postordertraversse(top.left):
         m.append(top.root)
         top_most=m.pop(0)

conv=createlist();
conv.postordertraversse(conv.top)
```

What i can understand is if top  means `if top` object instance exists then move inside the block and check `if not` i.e **till top.left is not null keep appending**.

Comment: There isn't any loop in your example - so not keep appending until "null".

Answer (score 4):

`if x:` means "if x is truthy".

`if not x:` means "if x is falsey".

Whether something is *truthy* or *falsey* depends on what kind of object it is.

For numbers, `0` is falsey, and all other values are truthy.

For boolean values, `True` is truthy and `False` is falsey (obviously!)

For collections (lists, tuples, dictionaries, strings, etc), empty ones are falsey and non-empty ones are truthy.

So in your example code, the two `if` statements are saying:

> if top is truthy:
>
> if the *result* of self.postordertraversse(top.left) is falsey:

Comment: so  it means my function is checking if it is getting return values as 0,False or no values then execute the statements in if ,correct? @John Gordon

Comment: Yes.  However I just noticed that the function is calling _itself_, and it never `return`s anything, therefore it will return `None` by default, so the `if` will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

not in python is like negation in other programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

'not' statement just converts further expression. For example:

```
not True - False
not False - True
```